# Запретить выделение объекта

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

При создании календаря те дни недели, которые не входят в текущий месяц у меня создаются как просто пустые ячейки таблицы. Но на эти пустые ячейки действуют все события: hover, click и т.д. Проблема в том можно ли как-то сделать так, что если ячейка пустая на нее нельзя кликнуть и выделить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#table td").click(function() {
   var selected = $(this).hasClass("selected");
    $("#table td").removeClass("selected");
    if(!selected)
            $(this).addClass("selected");
   
   });
  });
var day = ['пн', 'вт', 'ср', 'чт', 'пт', 'сб', 'вс'];
var month = ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май','Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'];
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = i;
     option.text = month[i];
     monthList.appendChild(option);
 } 
 for (var i = 1940; i < 2100; i++) {
     var option = document.createElement("option");
     option.value = i;
     option.text = i;
     yearList.appendChild(option);
 }
var currentDate = new Date();
var today = currentDate.getDate();
var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth();
var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
var calendarDate = new Date();
var calendarMonth = calendarDate.getMonth();
var calendarYear = calendarDate.getFullYear();
var tElement=document.createElement('table');
tElement.id = 'table';
document.getElementById('tableDiv').appendChild(tElement);
for(var i = 0; i < day.length; i ++){
 var th=document.createElement('th');
 th.innerHTML = day[i];
 document.getElementById('table').appendChild(th);
}

var trs=[],tds=[];
monthList.value = calendarMonth;
yearList.value = calendarYear;

function changeTable(calendarYear, calendarMonth)
{
    var d = new Date(calendarYear, calendarMonth, 1);
    var date = new Date();
    var t = d.getDay() - 1;
    if(t < 0)
        t = 6;
    var a = 0;
    while(d.getMonth() === calendarMonth || a<trs.length)
    {
        if(trs[a]===undefined)
            trs[a]=document.createElement('tr');
        var i = 0;
        while(i < 7)
        {
            if(tds[a*7+i]===undefined)
                tds[a*7+i]=document.createElement('td');
      if(a == 0 && i < t || d.getMonth() != calendarMonth)
          tds[a*7+i].innerHTML = '';
            else
            {
                if(String(d.getDate()).length==1)
                    tds[a*7+i].innerHTML = d.getDate();
                else tds[a*7+i].innerHTML = d.getDate();
                tds[a*7+i].style="text-align: center";
                d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
      }
            trs[a].appendChild(tds[a*7+i]);
            i++;
        }
        document.getElementById('table').appendChild(trs[a]);
        tElement.appendChild(trs[a]);
        a++;
 }
 var count = 0;
 for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++){
  if(tds[i].innerHTML == '')
   count++;
 }
 if(monthList.value == currentMonth && yearList.value == currentYear)
  tds[today + count - 1].style = "border: 1px solid #A5B5BC; border-radius: 50%";
 $("#table td").removeClass("selected");
}
changeTable(calendarYear,calendarMonth);
prevMonth.onclick=function()
{
    if(monthList.value == 0){
     yearList.value--;
     monthList.value = 11;
     changeTable(yearList.value, monthList.value);
    }else{
     monthList.value--;
     changeTable(yearList.value, monthList.value);
    }
}

nextMonth.onclick=function()
{
 if(monthList.value == 11){
     yearList.value++;
     monthList.value = 0;
     changeTable(yearList.value, monthList.value);
    }else{
     monthList.value++;
     changeTable(yearList.value, monthList.value);
    }
}
```

```css
th{
 vertical-align: middle;
 color: #8b9295;
 font:normal normal 14px 'Open Sans',Arial,sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
}

td:hover{
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: #e4f2fd;
}

td.selected { 
    border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: #1A7FD4;
 color: #FFFFFF; 
}
#tableDiv{
 border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
 width: 280px;
 height: 280px;
 background: #FFFFFF;
 text-align: center;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    font:normal normal 14px 'Open Sans',Arial,sans-serif;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 14px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);

  
}
#table{
 width: 280px;
 height: 280px;
 background: #FFFFFF;
 font:normal normal 14px 'Open Sans', Arial ,sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 
</head>

<body>
 <div id = "headDiv"> 
   <input type="button" align="left" id="prevMonth"  value="&#8249;">
    <select id = "monthList" onchange="changeTable(yearList.value, monthList.value)"></select>
    <select id = "yearList"  onchange="changeTable(yearList.value, monthList.value)"></select>
   <input type = "button" align="right" id="nextMonth"  value="&#8250;">
 </div>
  <div id = "tableDiv">  
  </div> 
<script src = 'main.js'></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но проблема в том что при перелистывании месяца созданный класс остается и числа меняются, а выделить я некоторые из них не могу т.к. у них класс "empty". Пытался на событие onclick и onchange поставить удаление этого класса, но это не сработало. Не подскажите в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допишите неприменение этой функции к классу (например .empty)

```
$("#table td:not(.empty)").click(function() {
    var selected = $(this).hasClass("selected");
    $("#table td").removeClass("selected");
    if(!selected)
        $(this).addClass("selected");       
});
```

И при создании элемента, если он пустой, допишите к нему необрабатываемый класс (например .empty)

```
tds[a*7+i]=document.createElement('td');
        if(a == 0 && i < t || d.getMonth() != calendarMonth){
            tds[a*7+i].innerHTML = '';
            tds[a*7+i].addClass('empty');
        }
```

Так же измените стиль

```
td:not(.empty){
    ...
}
```

Если же требуется очищать классы при смене месяца:

```
$('#nextMonth, #prevMonth').on('click', function(){
    $('#table td').removeClass('empty');
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, но проблема в том что при перелистывании месяца созданный класс остается и числа меняются, а выделить я некоторые из них не могу т.к. у них класс "empty". Пытался на событие onclick и onchange поставить удаление этого класса, но это не сработало. Не подскажите в чем проблема?

Comment: @mhz Вы имеете ввиду то, что я дописал в конец ответа?

Comment: Да, спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Это можно на `css` реализовать при помощи псевдокласса `:empty` и свойства `pointer-events` :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#table td").click(function() {
    var selected = $(this).hasClass("selected");
    $("#table td").removeClass("selected");
    if (!selected)
      $(this).addClass("selected");

  });
});
var day = ['пн', 'вт', 'ср', 'чт', 'пт', 'сб', 'вс'];
var month = ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'];
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = i;
  option.text = month[i];
  monthList.appendChild(option);
}
for (var i = 1940; i < 2100; i++) {
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = i;
  option.text = i;
  yearList.appendChild(option);
}
var currentDate = new Date();
var today = currentDate.getDate();
var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth();
var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
var calendarDate = new Date();
var calendarMonth = calendarDate.getMonth();
var calendarYear = calendarDate.getFullYear();
var tElement = document.createElement('table');
tElement.id = 'table';
document.getElementById('tableDiv').appendChild(tElement);
for (var i = 0; i < day.length; i++) {
  var th = document.createElement('th');
  th.innerHTML = day[i];
  document.getElementById('table').appendChild(th);
}

var trs = [],
  tds = [];
monthList.value = calendarMonth;
yearList.value = calendarYear;

function changeTable(calendarYear, calendarMonth) {
  var d = new Date(calendarYear, calendarMonth, 1);
  var date = new Date();
  var t = d.getDay() - 1;
  if (t < 0)
    t = 6;
  var a = 0;
  while (d.getMonth() === calendarMonth || a < trs.length) {
    if (trs[a] === undefined)
      trs[a] = document.createElement('tr');
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 7) {
      if (tds[a * 7 + i] === undefined)
        tds[a * 7 + i] = document.createElement('td');
      if (a == 0 && i < t || d.getMonth() != calendarMonth)
        tds[a * 7 + i].innerHTML = '';
      else {
        if (String(d.getDate()).length == 1)
          tds[a * 7 + i].innerHTML = d.getDate();
        else tds[a * 7 + i].innerHTML = d.getDate();
        tds[a * 7 + i].style = "text-align: center";
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
      }
      trs[a].appendChild(tds[a * 7 + i]);
      i++;
    }
    document.getElementById('table').appendChild(trs[a]);
    tElement.appendChild(trs[a]);
    a++;
  }
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    if (tds[i].innerHTML == '')
      count++;
  }
  if (monthList.value == currentMonth && yearList.value == currentYear)
    tds[today + count - 1].style = "border: 1px solid #A5B5BC; border-radius: 50%";
  $("#table td").removeClass("selected");
}
changeTable(calendarYear, calendarMonth);
prevMonth.onclick = function() {
  if (monthList.value == 0) {
    yearList.value--;
    monthList.value = 11;
    changeTable(yearList.value, monthList.value);
  } else {
    monthList.value--;
    changeTable(yearList.value, monthList.value);
  }
}

nextMonth.onclick = function() {
  if (monthList.value == 11) {
    yearList.value++;
    monthList.value = 0;
    changeTable(yearList.value, monthList.value);
  } else {
    monthList.value++;
    changeTable(yearList.value, monthList.value);
  }
}
```

```css
th {
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #8b9295;
  font: normal normal 14px 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

td:hover {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #e4f2fd;
}

td.selected {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #1A7FD4;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#tableDiv {
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  width: 280px;
  height: 280px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  font: normal normal 14px 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
}

#table {
  width: 280px;
  height: 280px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  font: normal normal 14px 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}


/*Магия*/

td:empty {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="headDiv">
  <input type="button" align="left" id="prevMonth" value="&#8249;">
  <select id="monthList" onchange="changeTable(yearList.value, monthList.value)"></select>
  <select id="yearList" onchange="changeTable(yearList.value, monthList.value)"></select>
  <input type="button" align="right" id="nextMonth" value="&#8250;">
</div>
<div id="tableDiv">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, не знал об этом.